# Exponential sums with prime power modulus

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, exponential-sums

I am looking for an analogue of the following result of Fouvry and Katz for prime power modulus ("A general stratification theorem for exponential sums, and applications", J. reine angew. Math. **540** (2001), 115-166), which states:

Theorem (Fouvry-Katz): Let $n,d$ be positive integers and let $V$ be a locally-closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{z}}^n$ with complex dimension at most $d$. Let $f(\mathbf{x})$ be an element in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$.

Then there exists a number $C(n,d,f,V)$, closed subschemes $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ of relative dimension $n -j$ and $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Z}}^n \supset X_1 \supset \cdots \supset X_n$ such that for any invertible function $g$ on $V$, any prime $p$, any $h \in \mathbb{A}^n(\mathbb{F}_p) \setminus X_j(\mathbb{F}_p)$  we have

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \sum_{\mathbf{x} \in V(\mathbb{F}_p)} \chi(g(\mathbf{x})) \psi(f(\mathbf{x}) + h_1 x_1 + \cdots + h_n x_n) \right \rvert \leq C(n,d,f,V) p^{\frac{d}{2} + \frac{j-1}{2}}$$

for every non-trivial additive character $\psi$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$ and for every multiplicative character (possibly trivial) $\chi$ of $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$.

In particular, I ask whether there exists an analogous bound for exponential sums of the form

$$\displaystyle \sum_{\mathbf{x} \in V(\mathbb{Z}/p^2 \mathbb{Z})} \exp\left(2\pi i\left(h_1 x_1 + \cdots + h_n x_n \right)/p^2 \right)$$

of the quality as in the above theorem of Fouvry and Katz.